# Multiple video downloading using NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, nsoperationqueue

I have code following lines to start multiple downloads from my application. The problem is, the NSInvocationQueue is not calling selector method, i.e. **downloadMyVideos**.

Can please anyone let me know, exactly what is wrong with following code?

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
        operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];

        indexOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(downloadMyVideo) object:nil];
        [operationQueue addOperation:indexOperation];
    }
```

Comment: Do you see (multiple) memory leaks there? Because I think I do.

Comment: @Jacob: Yes! Or, perhaps it's time to start getting used to ARC questions...

Comment: Jacob Relkin: It's not warning me for any kind of memory leak. The console shows no words in it.

Comment: Maybe he's using Xcode 3 without the Static Analyser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've suspended your queue.

Operations that you add to a suspended queue are not run. That could be your problem, unless you are starting the queue elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Abizern, the method is started executing as I have removed the [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];.

Comment: Both of the following questions are being asked in context to maintain NSOperationQueue.                                                     As I am going to use this code to download multiple videos, how do I remove/release added NSInvocationOperation from NSOperationQueue after competition of downloading a video? And also, what should  I do if in case I want to stop to download  specific video?